# Scanning thorugh lists inside a dictionary of selected groups

Tags: python

Consider a dictionary like this:

```
dic={ 'PC2': ['02:02:02:02:02:02', '192.168.0.2', '200'],
    'PC3': ['03:03:03:03:03:03', '192.168.0.3', '200'],
    'PC1': ['01:01:01:01:01:01', '192.168.0.1', '200'] }
```

How do I search for a particular value inside a list? First, I want the user to input the hostname and ip. e.g. `'PC1'` and `192.168.0.1`, and then I need to find out if `192.168.0.1` has already been assigned to some other host in dictionary. In this case I would need to skip searching inside the list assigned to the user's input host.

In other words, if user inputs `'PC1'` and `192.168.0.1`, I would like to skip searching in `'PC1'`'s values. So it should detect matches only with different hosts, skipping `'PC1'`.

If I input `'PC4'` and `192.168.0.1`, then it should detect a conflict with PC1. So PC4 would not be inserted, or would be deleted if already present.

My current solution:

```
z=raw_input("Enter Host, Mac, ip and time")
t=z.split()
t[0]=z[1:]
for key in dic:
    if t[2] in dic[key]:
        del dic[t[0]]
    else:
        dic[t[0]] = t[1:]
```

Comment: why do you use a list? it doesn't support well the operations you need.

Comment: what is `dic` and why you override `z`?

Comment: and why you override `t[0]`, don't you want it to hold the host names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you want is `ip->host` dictionary,
so given ip & host, you can easily check if any of them was already used.

```
ip2host = {dic[key][1]:key for key in dic.keys()}
```

(you can already use `dic` for `host->ip` dictionary)

then you can do something like:

```
host,mac,ip = raw_input("Enter Host, Mac, ip and time").split()

ip2host = {dic[key][1]:key for key in dic.keys()}
if host in dic.keys()
    # <Override in db or whatever you want to do here>
    dic[host][0] = mac
    dic[host][1] = ip
else:
    # <add to DB code here>
    if ip in ip2host.keys():
        # <deleted just added host>
```

Note that you need to replace my comment with your DB access code.
in addition, I am not sure I understood all your needs but maybe you can hold list of `ips` instead of `ip2host` dictionary.
you can create such list like that:

```
ips = [dic[k][1] for k in dic.keys()]
```

Comment: Tried got error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/b.py", line 11, in <module>
    for key in dic:
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Comment: @user3238040 it was a problem with with code i copied from yours but I think I've fixed it. try it now. (i've added `.keys()`)

Comment: btw, I don't think it is a good idea to save your files under `c:/Python27/`

Comment: I have lists for keys. What I want is if host already exists it would overwrite otherwise add to database. And if host doesn't exist it will first add this host to database and then compare its IP with IPs of rest of hosts. If ip matches with any of the other hosts, it will delete the host that it just added now.I know it doesn't make sense but I need to do it.

Comment: maybe now is what you needs?

Comment: Yes, I want list of IPs to be stored like you said and then comparison would be easy for new ip.

Comment: so what the problem with the current answer?

Comment: What is k in ips variable?

Comment: key in dic.keys(). its a list comprhension.